# JQuery - how to get the app object from a button click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my javascript file, I have defined an app object that takes an initialization function which is triggered upon document `ready` via JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("JQuery ready");

    app.initialize();
});
```

The app is defined as

```
var app = {
  _GPS_ENABLED: false,

  initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
        // deviceready Event Handler
        $(document).on('deviceready', function() {
          ... ...
          // BIND A CLICK EVENT TO A FUNCTION DEFINED IN A LATER STEP
          $('#isGPSenabled').on("click", self.isGPSenabled);
          ... ...
        });
  },

  isGPSenabled: function() {
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isGpsLocationEnabled(function(enabled) {
        // HERE I NEED TO ACCESS THE "APP" ATTRIBUTE "_GPS_ENABLED"
        ._GPS_ENABLED = enabled;  // HOW CAN I ACCESS THE _GPS_ENABLED ATTRIBUTE ON APP
    });
  }
}
```

The HTML part has:

```
<button id = "isGPSenabled">IS GPS ENABLED</button>
```

How can I access the app's attribute from the function attached to a button?

Comment: `self` is a reserved word in Javascript and should not be used as a variable name. The question itself is unclear.

Comment: @Pyromonk [`self` is not reserved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar).

Comment: As far as the question goes: Why not do it the same way you did with `var self = this`... `self.isGPSenabled`? Store a reference to the object scope and refer to it within your nested function.

Comment: In the nested function, the "this" object is referenced by as the actual Button element as the parent function is bound to a click event "$('#isGPSenabled').on("click", self.isGPSenabled);"

Comment: @TylerRoper, thank you for clarifying. I still think it's a bad idea to use it (or to use `this`, for that matter).

Comment: Well you can't use `this` because that *is* a reserved keyword. `let this = "Hello world" // SyntaxError: unexpected token: keyword 'this'`. If you don't want to use `self`, I've also seen `let _this = this` or even `let that = this`.

Comment: So what is the best option that I should use given that this is referenced as the Button element?

Answer (score 0):

Previously I've referenced the object by it's name within itself. I think it was a pattern I saw once which worked for my needs at the time. Haven't really thought about the positives or negatives much but it has never caused me any issues in previous work.

Here is an example to to demonstrate:

```js
const app = {
  isEnabled: null,
  init: () => {
    app.isEnabled = false;
  },
  toggleEnabled: () => {
    app.isEnabled = !app.isEnabled;
  },
  displayEnabled: () => {
    console.log('isEnabled?:', app.isEnabled);
  }
}

app.displayEnabled(); // null
app.init();
app.displayEnabled(); // false
app.toggleEnabled();
app.displayEnabled(); // true
```